# Set javascript global variables across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, global-variables, persistent-storage

I want to store global variables in javascript array to make them available for multiple pages.

I know that cookies or localstorage can do similar things. But I want to store lots of information therefore it would be better if I can figure out a way to store them in javascript array.

For example, in html 1 file

```
<head>
    <title>Global javascript example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="global_var['a']['a']=1;"> a,a set to 1  </button>  
    <br/>                              
    <button type="button" onclick="global_var['a']['b']=1;"> a,b set to 1  </button>             
    <br/>                              
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(global_var['a']['b']);"> echo  a,b   </button>  
</body>
```

Now in another html file or the same page after refresh, I want to access the global variable:

```
<head>
    <title>Global javascript example</title>
</head>
<body>                            
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(global_var['a']['b']);"> echo a,b </button>               
</body>
```

Is there any way to implement this other than using cookies?

Comment: I think only with frames, and set you global vars to your 'top'

Comment: cookies, localstorage, iframe, ajax, any method that persists data across a page refresh.

Answer (score 24):

The short answer is:

```
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

and then:

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
```

The long answer is http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. What about on browser that does not support html5?

Comment: That's what servers are for.

Comment: @user2818066 browsers down to IE8 support localstorage. If you need to go lower than IE8 - you've got problem.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* store array (or any other object) into local storage. All you need is `JSON.stringify` to convert any object (including array) into string to place into the storage and `JSON.parse` to convert it back into the object after retrieving it from the storage.

Here's quick reference: http://samcroft.co.uk/2013/using-localstorage-to-store-json/

Answer (score 2):

Consider using localStorage as [nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586181/nicholas) mentioned which holds your comfortable amount of memory like 5MB to unlimited depending on browser capabilities.

If you are still not convinced with cookies or localStorage which are straightforward methods try using libraries like [sessvarsJS](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessvars.js)

A detailed tutorial & demo can be found at [Session variables without cookies](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html)

Comment: pretty cool tool that yes!